# Accessing loop variable in other methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have the following method:

```
def run
  @users.each do |u|
    ..
    ..
  end
end
```

I have a lot of code in `run` so I am trying to refactor it and splitting it up into smaller methods. One of these methods is the following:

```
def finish_mutation
  ..
  ..
  Rails.logger.info "Succesfully added #{u.name}"
end
```

This breaks because `finish_mutation` doesn't have access to the `u` variable. How can I create new methods that can access the `u` variable that I created in `run`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply create method taking parameter:

```
def finish_mutation(user)
  # code
  Rails.logger.info "Successfully added #{user.name}"
end
```

and call it, passing `User` instance:

```
finish_mutation(u)
```

Answer (score 3):

it's easy to do you just add a parameter to your finish_mutation method like this :

```
def finish_mutation(param)
   # .......
end
```

then you call your function like this :

```
def run
  @users.each do |u|
    ..
    ..

    finish_mutation(u)  # <----- for example here you call your method

  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes passing your loop variable (as shown in the other answers) is the best answer.  Sometimes you can DRY things up better by adding a method to whatever class 'u' is an instance of.  So you might do

```
class User
def finish_mutation
 # put your operation here
end
end
```

And then in your loop

```
u.finish_mutation
```

Obviously you need to think about which is the best way for a specific case.